# OrbitController change orbit JS (Three JS)

Tags: three.js, controls

Hi I am using OrbitController for my simple WebGL program.

I do notice that OrbitControls only orbits on point 0,0,0.

Is there a way to change its orbit to be around an object? (perhaps onclick)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [browse the source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L28), you will find a variable called target. And it is commented as follows:

```
// "target" sets the location of focus, where the control orbits around
// and where it pans with respect to.
```

Seems to me that this is exactly is what you need.

Comment: Thank you. Apologies as I am still very new to three js